# Create a regex that matches when there are non repeating characters of a particular type

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to create a regex that matches when there are no repeating characters of a particular type and all other characters are ignored. Word length does not matter. Ex.

```
hippos-R-Y-S <--- Matches
hippos-R-Y-Y <--- Does not match
hippos-R-Y-P <--- Matches
```

Again, the `hippos-` text could be anything, but the capital letters that follow have to be in the set of `[YRPS]`. Thanks for your help!!

Comment: Are the strings always formatted like that `^anything-[YRPS]-[YRPS]-[YRPS]$`?

Comment: [**`/^(?![^-]*-.*?([A-Z]).*?\1)[^-]*(-[YRPS]){3}$/m`**](https://www.regex101.com/r/3nNss7/1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex based on 2 negative lookaheads to skip matching repeated character in `[YRPS]` class:

```
^[^-]+-([YRPS])(?:-(?!\1)([YRPS])(?!.*\2))+$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/fEALOK/5)

**RegEx Breakup:*

```
^           # line start
[^-]+       # match 1 or more of any char that is not a -
-           # match literal -
([YRPS])    # match [YRPS] and group it #1
(?:         # start non-capturing group
   -        # match literal -
   (?!\1)   # negative lookahead to assert next char is not same as group #1
   ([YRPS]) # match [YRPS] and group it #2
   (?!.*\2) # negative lookahead to assert next char is not same as group #2
)+          # end non-capture group and + makes it match 1 or more of the same set
$           # end of line
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do the job:

```
^.*?-([YRPS])-(?!\1)([YRPS])-(?!\1)(?!\2)([YRPS])$
```

**Explanation:**

```
^           : begining of string
  .*?-      : 0 or more any char until dash
  ([YRPS])  : one of the set, captured in group 1
  -         : a dash
  (?!\1)    : negative lookahead, not the same letter as in group 1
  ([YRPS])  : one of the set, captured in group 2
  -         : a dash
  (?!\1)    : negative lookahead, not the same letter as in group 1
  (?!\2)    : negative lookahead, not the same letter as in group 2
  ([YRPS])  : one of the set, captured in group 3
$           : end of string
```